# React Native InitialRouteName

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I'm using React Native v5.0 and trying to set a nested navigation for my app, however, the prop "initialRouteName" don't seem to work, even if i set it alone without any React Redux code or the nested function it still wont work, how is that prop supposed to work?

````
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import SignIn from './pages/SigIn';
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';

const AppStack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Home() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function Routes() {
  const Signed = useSelector((state) => state.auth.signed);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppStack.Navigator
        initial={Home}
        initialRouteName={Signed ? Home : SignIn}
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      >
        <AppStack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
        <AppStack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
        <AppStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </AppStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot strings

---

```
 initialRouteName={Signed ? "Home" : "SignIn"}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this approach, you should split stacks. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/auth-flow

Comment: you can create separated groups instead of separating the whole stack ( https://reactnavigation.org/docs/group/ ), but according to his question this was his error

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, we should not keep authorized screens and non-authorized screens in one stack. This is so called pattern of "protected routes". Each stack may have its own `initialRouteName` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/auth-flow

```
isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </>
)
```